# React-native animation lagging on android

Tags: react-native, animation, expo, react-native-reanimated, react-native-reanimated-v2

I'm using the Reanimated library(2.2.0), and I have a fairly simple animation to expand a Animated.View , that I call when pressing a TouchableOpacity:

```
    height.value = withTiming(calculatedHeight, {
      duration: 300,
      easing: Easing.inOut(Easing.ease),
    });
```

On IOS is running very nice on 60fps, but on some Android phones like Samsung S20,S21 Ultra, the animation is lagging a lot. I tried it on an older Samsung(A5) and on it is running fine again. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: yeah, this seems to be a real problem. I'm also using a samsung s21 I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animate the Y scale instead of the height. left top width height are slow